# JSP file not rendering in Spring Boot running in AppEngine

Tags: java, maven, jsp, google-app-engine, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot Application running using Google App Engine Standard Runtime. When I try to render JSP views from the controller, it's not rendering.

Here are my Maven dependencies,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <version>9.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

My Controller Class trying to render calendar.jsp,

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping("/hello")
public String hello()
{
    return "calendar";
}
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

While executing the command

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

I'm getting following exceptions

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.catalina.Context.addServletMapping(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at com.spring.config.Application.main(Application.java:19) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:527) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

[Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDvbM.png)

[Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kX3d.png)

Thanks for the help in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like spring boot is relying on catalina as the servlet engine (eg. tomcat)

Could it be that google's app engine doesn't support that?

Try reading through this google guide specifically relating to spring boot and app engine https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-app-engine-springboot/index.html

You claim this issue is that you're returning a string "hello", which is strange, try looking at this https://hellokoding.com/spring-boot-hello-world-example-with-jsp/

Comment: I created my Spring Boot application as per the link you mentioned. But if I remove this "tomcat-embed-jasper" dependency the exception is not thrown and JSP not rendering.

Comment: well, when you say not rendering, what's happening instead? are there any errors in the log?

Comment: No handler mapping found for [/hello]

Comment: I solved the no handler mapping found, still my jsp's are not rendering.No exceptions in logs. In the browser, its just printing "calendar" as a string.

Comment: where are your files? Can you send a screenshot of your directory structure?

Comment: @ zack6849 added directory structure to the question